# Use any value of an enum in a Typescript interface

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript interface

```
export interface MyInterface {
  valid: boolean;
  resourceType: MyEnum;
  message: string;
}
```

and an enum

```
enum MyEnum {
  'a',
  'b',
  'c'
}
```

Is it possible to allow the value of MyInterface.resourceType to be any value from MyEnum?

Currently my IDE is throwing an error

```
property 'resourceType' of exported interface has or is using private 
name 'MyEnum'
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully. You need to `export enum MyEnum { ... }`, so that other parts of the app can access it to see what valid values there are.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed something so simple haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exporting the enum

```
export enum MyEnum {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
  c = 'c'
}
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed something so simple haha. Thank you!